# Maven assembly JAR in EAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, ear

For reasons that I won't go into, I need to build the following structure:

```
EAR
 |
 |-- Uber-JAR
 |
 |-- WAR
```

I can build the uber JAR with the Maven Assembly plugin, but when I try to include it in the EAR (built with the Maven EAR plugin) it includes a normal JAR version, which has no sources (because I'm using the uber JAR to pull all the sources in the project together).

How can I get the uber JAR included in the EAR?

Comment: Does the Uber jar that you're building include a classifier in it's Maven GAV?

Comment: No... would that help?

Comment: You use the classifier to distinguish the uber jar artifact from the regular jar that is produced by your maven build. Typically this is derived from the `id` element of your assembly.xml. You can then refer to the uber jar by including the `classifier` element in the EAR dependencies and EAR plugin artifact configuration as well.

Comment: Ah right, nice one. I'll have a look at that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to fix it. If there's a better way I'd like to know it :)

Just include:

```
<earSourceDirectory>${basedir}</earSourceDirectory>
<earSourceIncludes>/path/to/jar.jar</earSourceIncludes>
```

in the EAR plugin configuration.

EDIT: Seems I spoke too soon. In the project's parent pom I have all the modules listed to build, with the uber JAR above the EAR module (as the last two modules).

It won't build the whole project:

```
'Artifact <ARTIFACT> (included by module) does not have an artifact with a file'
```

**EDIT (again):**

**Final Answer**

So, finally, in the configuration for the Maven Assembly plugin, I have:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <finalName>myjarname</finalName>
</configuration>
```

This creates a JAR file called simply 'myjarname.jar'.

In the Maven EAR plugin configuration, I use the following structure:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <modules>
        ...
        <ejbModule>
            <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
            <bundleFileName>myjarname.jar</bundleFileName>
        </ejbModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
```

This grabs the specific jar and puts it in the EAR. Voila!